# How can I show that a map is an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Prove that the map

$$\operatorname{Mat}_{nxn}(\mathbb{F}) \times \operatorname{Mat}_{nxn}(\mathbb{\mathbb{F}})\to \mathbb{F}, \quad (A,B) \mapsto tr(B^{t}A)$$

is an inner product on $\operatorname{Mat}_{nxn}(\mathbb{F}).$

I know that we have to show that the map will preserve conjugate symmetry, linearity in first argument, and positive-definiteness. How do I write this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say "conjugate symmetry", so I'll assume your field is the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$.  The regular transpose doesn't work: you need the conjugate transpose: $A^H \equiv {\overline {A^T}}$.  Then the inner product is $\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(A^H B)$.  Most of the requirements for inner product (such as the sesquilinearity) are easy to verify.  For the conjugate symmetry, use the fact that $\operatorname{Tr}(C E)=\operatorname{Tr}(E C)$ if $CE$ and $EC$ are both well-defined (hence both square).  The hardest part is positive-definiteness: showing $\operatorname{Tr}(A^H A)>0$ if $A \neq 0$.  There may be some theorem you can use involving the eigenvalues of $A$, etc., but that theorem might use what you are trying to prove.  You can calculate $\operatorname{Tr}(A^H A)>0$ directly using the definitions of trace, conjugate transpose, and trace, and eventually you get:

$$  \operatorname{Tr}(A^H A) = \sum_{i,j=1}^n |a_{i,j}|^2.$$

The right-hand side is obviously real, nonnegative, and is zero if and only if $A= 0$.  The square root of the right-hand side is called the Frobenius norm or the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of $A$.

EDIT: my definition above is linear in the second argument and conjugate-linear in the second argument, which is the way most mathematicians do it.  You might have to modify it if you want the inner product to be linear in the first argument and conjugate-linear in the second argument.  Of course, if your "F" is the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, this is not a problem.

Comment: The book that I am using assumes that F may be the reals or complex space. Also, it defines an inner product with the five properties positivity, definiteness, additivity in first slot, homogeneity in first slot, and conjugate symmetry in C. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want "homogeneity" in the first slot (most people would say "linearity".  "Homogeneity" is typically used with norms, e.g. for any norm $\|\cdot \|$, you need $\|c\mathbf{x}\| = |c|\|\mathbf{x}\|$, when you want the absolute value (for real $c$) or modulus (for complex $c$) on the right hand side.  When you don't need absolute value (or modulus) most people would just say "linearity".  Leaving that quibble aside, I'll continue), you'd define $\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(A^T\, {\overline B})$.  This seems to be less popular than the above, perhaps because you have to do ..

Comment: ... somethng to both matrices, $A$ and $B$, instead of just doing something to $A$.

Comment: copper.hat makes a good observation.  This definition of inner product has the disadvantage that the positive-definiteness property is far from obvious, as is the equality of the resulting norm to the Frobenius norm.  I would not call this definition (using the trace) a computational trick, because when you compute inner products involving complicated expressions involving lots of matrices, you can take advantage of the properties of the trace operator (such as $\operatorname{Tr}(CE) = \operatorname{Tr}(EC)$, for example).

Comment: @StefanSmith: I agree, I traded off correctness for conciseness. The trace expression is **very** useful, but the utility is far from obvious when introduced first. I was really encouraging the OP not to focus on the trace aspect for this exercise.

Comment: @copper.hat : when I first encountered the trace definition, I found it puzzling.

Comment: It took me a surprisingly long time to make the connection between the trace definition and the Frobenius aspect. A bit sad given that I was in the control group at UC Berkeley...

Comment: @copper.hat : I just ground it out and found the norms were equal.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The trace map has the following properties

$$tr(A+B) = tr(A) + tr(B)$$
$$tr(cA) = ctr(A)$$
$$tr(A^{T}) = tr(A)$$

Comment: Also $\operatorname{tr} (A^TA) = 0$ iff all eigenvalues of the symmetric $A^T A$ are zero iff $A^T A$ is zero.

Comment: Helpful properties, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

Let $\phi:\{1,...,n^2 \} \to \{1,...,n \} \times \{1,...,n \}$ be the bijection defined by $\phi(k) = ((k-1 \mod m)+1, \lfloor \frac{k-1}{m}+1 \rfloor)$.

Let $i: \mathbb{F}^{m \times m} \to \mathbb{F}^{m^2}$ be the isomorphism defined by $[i(A)]_{k} = [A]_{\phi(k)}$. Then we have $\langle A,B \rangle_{\mathbb{F}^{m \times m}} = \operatorname{tr} (B^*A) = \sum_i [B^*A]_{ij} = \sum_{i,j} \overline{[B]_{ij}} [A]_{ij} = \sum_k \overline{[B]_{\phi(k)}} [A]_{\phi(k)} = \langle i(A),i(B) \rangle_{\mathbb{F}^{m^2}}$.

Since $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\mathbb{F}^{m^2}}$ is an inner product on $\mathbb{F}^{m^2}$, it follows that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\mathbb{F}^{m \times m}} $ is an inner product on $\mathbb{F}^{m \times m}$.

Note: The map $i$ just changes the matrix $A$ into one long column vector. That is $i(A) = \begin{bmatrix} [A]_{11} \\ [A]_{21} \\ \vdots \\ [A]_{n1} \\ \vdots \\ [A]_{1n} \\ [A]_{2n} \\ \vdots \\ [A]_{nn}  \end{bmatrix}$, and the computation above shows that the trace inner product is just the usual inner product of this long column vector.

Comment: I have not seen this done yet in my linear algebra course.

Comment: There are no tricks here, it just treats the matrix as a long vector with the columns stacked on on top of another. The matrix inner product above is just the 'standard' inner product applies to the stacked columns.

Comment: Understood, first time seeing this notation but it seems reasonable.

Comment: It is a very useful operation if you ever need to deal with derivatives of functions of matrices. The norm that is associated with this is called the Frobenius norm, and is useful in numerical computations because it is smooth and is easy to compute. The definition using the trace is a bit of a notational trick and a bit misleading at first.

Comment: See my comment to Stefan's answer to see an elaboration on my 'trick' comment.